# Communication with chef server/chef node without using knife

Tags: chef-infra

I would like to automate a server management using chef.

With the help of knife, i was able to

1. download cookbook from chef supermarket
2. Upload cookbook to chef server
3. Bootstrap the node

Is it possible to do these things without the help of knife.Can we use chef server api for doing all those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically yes, and #1 and #2 are only rarely done using `knife` these days anyway. Berkshelf and Policyfiles have taken those jobs, but those are both command line tools too, not APIs. They are generally amenable to being used in scripts though. As for #3, there isn't anything specific. the Fog gem has some generic SSH-based bootstrap APIs, anything beyond that you need to write yourself.